# how can i get timer in wpf mediaplayer

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

i have developed media player in WPF.but i did n't get timer for slider in that.how i will get that timer below is the my .cs file code.
i used dispatchertimer for timer.video is seeking but timer is not displaying with video.
seekbar not moving where i clicked in seekbar.plz help me .

thanks in advance.

```
     DispatcherTimer timer;
    public TimeSpan duration;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_tick);
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Window_Loaded);




    }
     private void mediaElement1_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (mediaElement1.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = mediaElement1.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
            slider1.Maximum = ts.TotalSeconds;
            slider1.SmallChange = 1;
            slider1.LargeChange = Math.Min(10, ts.Seconds / 10);
        }
        timer.Start();
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        slider1.Value = mediaElement1.Position.TotalSeconds;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

You can implement this but you will have to pass references to your controls/window because without having references to your controls, the thread/timer object cannot modify controls (ie text etc).

Hope that helps!

Edit: Sorry I misread, but definately check whether the timer youre using can make changes to your elements

Comment: Try extending the timer control and passing in slider1 control maybe?

Comment: Check whether your DispatcherTimer method can access and modify controls in the window.

Comment: how i will give references to controls/window

Comment: Have a read of this.  Its an extremely valuable article for future projects too : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx